# Adding up several rasters to show the change

Tags: qgis, python, raster, classification, opencv

I want to add several images such that their change is shown in different colors. Such as the following in which I simply added two  images in their grayscale. But I would like to have a colored representation of change when several images are added together. For instance for 50 images, I have their difference depicted in 50 different colors.

My code to add grayscale images is as follows:

```
imageA = cv2.imread('/2013.tif')
imageB = cv2.imread('/2014.tif')

grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

result = cv2.add(imageA,imageB)
```

[image: image A]

[image: image B]

[image: result]

Is there any opensource approach using Python/R for that?

Comment: How would you like to display positive and negative change? For example, for 50 rasters, say pixel stack at XY location has 30 neutral values, 15 positive values, and 5 negative values. What does the intended output look like in that situation?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is the solution you are looking for, but I think it works. If you want to show the change between rasters, this accomplishes that goal. This is the workflow for comparing the change between 2 rasters.

The workflow is: 
1. Convert rasters to vector using the GDAL: Polygonize tool
2. Use the QGIS: Difference tool to compare change(found under vector > geoprocessing > difference)

Here are a couple screenshots to illustrate the point. Step 1, two rasters overlaid on top of eachother:
[image]

Step 2, convert them both to polygons. They still look mostly the same, except now they are vector objects:
[image]

Step 3, use Difference tool to show change between them. This is the output of that tool by itself:
[image]

Here is a short python script to do this, showing an example of how to use these tools for a single instance. If you are comparing 50 rasters, you will have to loop through multiple files.

```
import processing

#print(help(processing.algorithmHelp('gdal:polygonize')   #for help documentation

#run GDAL:polygonize tool
polygonize_parameters = {
    'INPUT': '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/RasterLayer.tif',    #change this file path to your own
    'BAND': 1,
    'FIELD': 'DN',
    'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS': False,
    'OUTPUT': '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Polygonized.gpkg'}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:polygonize', polygonize_parameters)

#print(help(processing.algorithmHelp('qgis:difference')   #for help documentation

#run qgis:difference tool
difference_parameters = {
    'INPUT': '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Polygon1.gpkg',
    'OVERLAY': '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Polygon2.gpkg',
    'OUTPUT': 'ogr:dbname=\'/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Difference.gpkg\' table=\"Diff\" (geom) sql='}

processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:difference', difference_parameters)
```

One last tip, if you run these tools by themselves using the QGIS widget, you can steal the python code from the log tab.

Is this the sort of answer you are looking for?